Adding originating source hostname to email subject with Postfix
First I have Gmail SMTP working fine using Postfix from Debian 12 (using SASL). This works like a charm.
However, I am trying to modify the outgoing subject line of relayed email using Postfix header checks. I cannot get it to work.
[header_checks]
/^Subject:$/ REPLACE Subject: [CUSTOM TEXT] $1

[main.cf]
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks


I modified the header_checks file to:
/^Subject: (.+)$/ REPLACE Subject:[CUSTOM TEXT] $1

Success!

In the regular expression /^Subject:$/, $ matches the end of the line. This means it would only match the field name and the separator, but not the field body (RFC 5322, 2.2).

Header fields are lines beginning with a field name, followed by a colon (:), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF.

Removing the $ would make it match any subject, but you would also need a capture group inside parentheses () you can refer with the $1.

Any non-empty subject: /^Subject: (.+)$/
Any subject: /^Subject: (.*)$/

I would choose:
/^Subject: (.*)$/ REPLACE Subject: [CUSTOM TEXT] $1

